How to create new column based on data column in pandas?
I have a df with two columns, DATE and QUANTITY.  The df is indexed by DATE.  Here is a short example:



DATE
QUANTITY




01/010/2024
6


01/09/2024
3


01/08/2024
7


01/07/2024
7


01/06/2024
11


01/05/2024
4


01/04/2024
3


01/03/2024
2


01/02/2024
5


01/01/2024
6



I want to create a new column (AVG) with a running 5 day average.  For example, the value of column AVG, Row 1, would be the average of the values in the QUANTITY column in rows 2-6, in column AVG, row 2, the value would be the average of the QUANTITY column in rows 3-7, and so on.



DATE
QUANTITY
AVG




01/010/2024
6
6.4


01/09/2024
3
6.4


01/08/2024
7
5.4


01/07/2024
7
5


01/06/2024
11
4


01/05/2024
4
3.2


01/04/2024
3
2.6


01/03/2024
2
2.2


01/02/2024
5
6


01/01/2024
6
0



In my example table there are not many datapoints but in the actual table I am using there are years of data.  The bottom 5 rows will either average less than 5 data points (shown in the example, because there are not 5 prior days) or return an error, depending on how this is designed.  Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work at all.
I have done a lot of research.  I have considered using a lambda function but I still cannot find the correct syntax to:
get the average of
the index of column=quantity and row=current_row+1 through
the index of column=quantity and row=current_row+6.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to read the question asking guide to get better answers faster. I believe your question may have already been answered in this dicussion. Your implementation might look something like df['AVG'] = df['QUANTITY'].rolling(window=5).mean()

import pandas as pd

# Creating the DataFrame
data = {
    'DATE': ['01/10/2024', '01/09/2024', '01/08/2024', '01/07/2024', '01/06/2024', 
             '01/05/2024', '01/04/2024', '01/03/2024', '01/02/2024', '01/01/2024'],
    'QUANTITY': [6, 3, 7, 7, 11, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert DATE to datetime
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# Sort the DataFrame by DATE in descending order
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending=False)

# Shift the QUANTITY column by 1 position
df['SHIFTED_QUANTITY'] = df['QUANTITY'].shift(-1)

# Calculate the rolling average
df['AVG'] = df['SHIFTED_QUANTITY'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean()

# Drop the SHIFTED_QUANTITY column
df = df.drop(columns=['SHIFTED_QUANTITY'])

Output:
        DATE  QUANTITY  AVG
0 2024-01-10         6  6.4
1 2024-01-09         3  6.4
2 2024-01-08         7  5.4
3 2024-01-07         7  5.0
4 2024-01-06        11  4.0
5 2024-01-05         4  3.2
6 2024-01-04         3  2.6
7 2024-01-03         2  2.2
8 2024-01-02         5  6.0
9 2024-01-01         6  0.0

